# Find non alphanumeric characters except other non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex

I'm not good at regex and I need help.

This regex `"/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/"` will look for words or sentences that contain at letters, numbers, spaces and dashes all together.

I'm looking for a regex expression that will check and make sure that at a word or sentence does not contain non alphanumeric characters except **spaces**, **dashes**, **apostroph**, **letters**, **numbers** as shown in the example below:

- **Awesome 123** (should pass)
- **Cool** (should pass)
- **t-shirt** (should pass)
- **Great shoes** (shoud pass)
- **here.** (should fail because of the pointuation)
- **I'm good** (should pass)

Comment: What tool are you using your regexp with?

Comment: I had no idea I could use any tool for this. Doing some googling now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, the problem with your expression is that it will match what you do not want. The `[^..]` means match a character which is *not* within the square brackets. Adding `^` and `$` at the beginning and end respectively will ensure that you match the entire string.

Thus, your regex would become something like so: `^[A-Za-z0-9' -]+$`. An example of the regular expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/uK1pA7/1). What this means is that it instructs the engine to match letters (both upper and lower case), numbers,single quotation marks, white spaces and dashes. The `^` and `$` instruct the engine that the regular expression should match the entire string.

EDIT:

As per your comment, I have updated the regular expression to match either what you are asking in your question or else currency values. An updated version of the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/uK1pA7/2), and is as follows: `^(([A-Za-z0-9' -]+)|([$€]\d+([.,]\d{2})?))$`. This should match currency values which *do not have thousand seperators*. The decimal seperator it uses is either `,` or `.` since different cultures use different symbols.

Comment: Awesome! I now have `^[A-Za-z0-9' -]+$`.  Is there a way to improve it to also match strings (that look like money) like $1.00 for instance?

Comment: @Lomse: The `$1.00` breaks one of your rules, thus I suppose you want match in an either or fashion?

Comment: Yes please. How would that look like? Thanks

Comment: @Lomse: You're welcome. Please keep in mind that as is, the regex will accept only dollars and euros. Should you need to match more or less, simply add/remove whatever currency items you need from the group.

Comment: Got it! I saw how you added the currencies. Thanks